# Аналог mutex в Java

Tags: java

Есть задача предотвратить повторное выполнение приложения, пока оно же и выполняется. Т.е не допустить запуска второго экземпляра. В Си использовал мьютексы для решения данного вопроса, а что можно и нужно использовать в Java?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того, что приложение делает.
Если это какой-нибудь сервер, логично создавать `ServerSocket` с фиксированным адресом и портом.
Можно эксклюзивно заблокировать какой-то определённый файл:

```
FileChannel.open(Paths.get(".../file.lock"), StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE).tryLock()
```

(файл должен быть доступен на запись).
Вариант просто эксклюзивно создавать файл (`StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW`) не надёжен, т.к. нет гарантии, что вы сможете удалить файл при выходе, так что при следующем запуске приложение посчитает, что оно уже запущено.

Comment: Были у меня такие же мысли за файл или сокет. Но посчитал колхозом. Т.е каких то элегантных решений нету получается?

Comment: @Kamenev_D Колхоз/элегантность - дело субъективное. Мьютексов уровня ОС в java нет, потому что, возможно, их сложно реализовать кросс-платформенно. Если почитать похожие вопросы на английском SO ([раз](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194227/getting-exclusive-system-wide-lock-in-java), [два](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495757/how-to-check-if-two-instances-of-the-same-java-program-are-running)), то там предлагают то же, что и я, ну ещё native-вызовы.

Comment: Понятно. Если работать через файл, то приложение его открывает в монопольном режиме, а если открыть не получается, то следовательно приложение запущено. Правильно понял?

Comment: @Kamenev_D Нет, приложение открывает файл на запись в обычном режиме, а только потом пытается получить `FileLock`. Если получить не удалось - другое приложение уже запущено. Теоретически, наличие `FileLock` может препятствовать даже открытию файла в другом приложении, это надо проверять.